# selecting the body of an iframe with D3

Tags: javascript, iframe, d3.js

`d3.select("body")` lets me select the body of the current page. How would I select the body of an iframe'd page? In jquery you'd do `$('body', frames[frameName].document)`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select children of elements like this:

```
d3.selectAll("iframe body");
```

Comment: @MiguelVazq Can't really tell you why without seeing a complete example.